# What teams have won the Europa League the season after winning the Champions League?

Tags: football, trivia, uefa, champions-league, europa-league

I am looking for a list of football clubs (if any) that have won the UEFA Europa League the season immediately following on from where they won the UEFA Champions League.

I would also be interested in knowing the seasons (years) in which the wins occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It happened only to Chelsea**

Chelsea

- 2011/2012 Champions League winner
- 2012/2013 Europa League winner

Those are the table of [Champions League finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_finals) and [Europa League finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UEFA_Cup_and_Europa_League_finals)

Comment: Thanks, looks like you are correct. I fount [this](http://www.worldfootball.net/winner/champions-league/) and [this](http://www.worldfootball.net/winner/europa-league/) which made it fairly quick to scan though them to confirm your answer!

Comment: Up for you, I add those sources to my answer