# What teams have won the Champions League the season after winning the Europa League?

Tags: football, trivia, uefa, champions-league, europa-league

Have any football teams won the UEFA Champions League the season directly following on from when they won the Europa League?

If so, what teams were they, and in which seasons did they achieve their victories?

Comment: Have you considered to merge this question with [this](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/what-teams-have-won-the-europa-league-the-season-after-winning-the-champions-lea) one?

Comment: @Ale: I have not... to be honest, I am not sure how I would word it if I tried. Feel free to edit the other if you think you can (and I will remove this one if I like it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It happened only to Porto**

Porto

- 2002/2003 Europa League winner
- 2003/2004 Champions League winner

Those are the table of [Champions League finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_finals) and [Europa League finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UEFA_Cup_and_Europa_League_finals)

Comment: That's quite interesting, as had he not been sacked at Chelsea (the first time), then Mourinho may have been able to claim both this achievement and the reverse (CL > EL)... though as it *didn't* happen I suppose it's not really of much interest at all... haha!

Comment: Who's to say he would have won it in the first place...